# theorem counter and bclogo package (Miktex)

Tags: miktex

How to implement  a counter theorem using bclogo package?

```
\begin{bclogo}[couleur=blue!10,logo =\bcplume,noborder =true]{Theorem}

         Content ....

\end{bclogo}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{bclogo}[couleur=blue!10,logo =\bccle,noborder =true]{proof}

         Content ...

\end{bclogo}
```

A full copy of my code below :

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

 %Configuration de la feuille 

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,enumerate,graphicx,pgf,tikz,fancyhdr}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz,pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\usepackage{tabvar}
\usepackage[tikz]{bclogo}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{blkarray}
\newcommand{\mLabel}[1]{\mbox{$\scriptstyle{#1}$}}
\geometry{hmargin=2.2cm,vmargin=1.5cm}\pagestyle{fancy}
\lfoot{\bfseries Réduction des endomorphismes}
\rfoot{\bfseries\thepage}
\cfoot{}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.5pt} %Filet en bas de page



\begin{document} 
\begin{center}\textsc{{\huge Déterminant}}\end{center}
\section{Groupe symétrique}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{bclogo}[couleur=blue!10,logo =\bcplume,noborder =true]{Définition}
Une permutation de l'ensemble $\{1,\cdots ,n\}$ est une bijection de $\{1,\cdots,n\}$ dans lui-même. Le groupe symétrique, noté $\mathfrak{S}_n$ ou $S_n$, est l'ensemble des permutations de $\{1,\cdots ,n\}$
\end{bclogo}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\vskip0.5cm 
\begin{bclogo}[couleur=white!10,logo =\bccle,noborder =true]{Exemple}
La notation habituelle est :
$\sigma =\begin{pmatrix} 1&2&3&4 \\\sigma(1)&\sigma(2)&\sigma(3)&\sigma(4)\end{pmatrix}\in S_4$
\end{bclogo}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{bclogo}[couleur=blue!10,logo =\bcplume,noborder =true]{Lemme 1.2}
L'ensemble $S_n$ possède $n!$ éléments
\end{bclogo}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\vskip0.5cm 
\begin{bclogo}[couleur=white!10,logo =\bccle,noborder =true]{Preuve}
Pour $\sigma(1)$ on a $n$ choix possibles, pour $\sigma(2)$, puisque $\sigma(2)\ne \sigma(1)$, on a $n-1$ choix possibles, ainsi par reccurence immédiate pour $\sigma(i)$, on a $[n-(i-1)]$ choix possibles donc $\text{Card}(S_n)=n!$
\end{bclogo}
\noindent \textsc{\bf \Large }
\vskip0.5cm
\end{document}
```

Comment: If you want others to help, please make a full minimal example others can copy and test as is. That makes it a lot easier to help. Some may even never have heard of the bclogo package

Comment: @daleif I added a full copy of my code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should define your own environments:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,enumerate,graphicx,pgf,tikz,fancyhdr}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz,pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\usepackage{tabvar}
\usepackage[tikz]{bclogo}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{blkarray}

\newcommand{\mLabel}[1]{\mbox{$\scriptstyle{#1}$}}

\geometry{hmargin=2.2cm,vmargin=1.5cm,headheight=13.6pt}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\lfoot{\bfseries Réduction des endomorphismes}
\rfoot{\bfseries\thepage}
\cfoot{}

\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.5pt} %Filet en bas de page

\newenvironment{definition}
 {%
  \begin{bclogo}[couleur=blue!10,logo=\bcplume,noborder=true]{Définition}%
 }
 {\end{bclogo}}

\newenvironment{example}
 {%
  \begin{bclogo}[couleur=white!10,logo=\bccle,noborder=true]{Exemple}%
 }
 {\end{bclogo}}

\newenvironment{proof}[1][Preuve]
 {\begin{bclogo}[couleur=white!10,logo=\bccle,noborder=true]{#1}}
 {\end{bclogo}}

\newcounter{theorem}
\counterwithin{theorem}{section}

\newenvironment{theorem}[1][Théorème]
 {%
  \refstepcounter{theorem}
  \begin{bclogo}[couleur=blue!10,logo =\bcplume,noborder =true]{#1 \thetheorem}%
 }
 {\end{bclogo}}


\begin{document} 

\section{Groupe symétrique}

\begin{definition}
Une permutation de l'ensemble $\{1,\cdots ,n\}$ est une bijection 
de $\{1,\cdots,n\}$ dans lui-même. Le groupe symétrique, noté 
$\mathfrak{S}_n$ ou $S_n$, est l'ensemble des permutations de 
$\{1,\cdots ,n\}$
\end{definition}

\begin{example}
La notation habituelle est :
$\sigma=\begin{pmatrix}
  1&2&3&4 \\
  \sigma(1)&\sigma(2)&\sigma(3)&\sigma(4)
\end{pmatrix}\in S_4$
\end{example}

\begin{theorem}[Lemme]\label{lem:factorial}
L'ensemble $S_n$ possède $n!$ éléments.
\end{theorem}

\begin{proof}
Pour $\sigma(1)$ on a $n$ choix possibles, pour $\sigma(2)$, 
puisque $\sigma(2)\ne \sigma(1)$, on a $n-1$ choix possibles, 
ainsi par reccurence immédiate pour $\sigma(i)$, on a $[n-(i-1)]$ 
choix possibles donc $\operatorname{Card}(S_n)=n!$
\end{proof}

\begin{theorem}\label{thm:factorial}
L'ensemble $S_n$ possède $n!$ éléments.
\end{theorem}

Le théorème~\ref{thm:factorial} est le même que le
lemme~\ref{lem:factorial}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The `theorem` environment has an optional argument for the tag (see the lemma). Also `proof` has an optional argument, if you want to do “Preuve du théorème” you can call it

```
\begin{proof}[Preuve du théorème]
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer and for this work. Just one thing, when I run the code, I've got an error message :<recently read> \counterwithin  and I tried to download the package "chngcntr" but I don't now where I sould put these files? I tried also to download it through the package manager, but it doesn't find this package.
                               
l.44 \counterwithin
                   {theorem}{section}

Comment: @Stu You should update your TeX distribution. In the meantime, replace `\newcounter{theorem}` with `\newcounter{theorem}[section]` and `\counterwithin{theorem}{section}` with `\renewcommand{\thetheorem}{\thesection.\arabic{theorem}}`.

Comment: Wonderfull, it works perfectly!!!!!