# Create blocks with different forms by using ``\bclogo``

Tags: color, bclogo

With the following codes

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{amsfonts,amsmath,amssymb,graphicx,amsthm}
\usepackage[tikz]{bclogo}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}
\usepackage{pifont} %bouni
\usepackage{fancybox} %pour faire l'encadrement
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{color}
%\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[final]{pdfpages} %pour inserer une page pdf
\usepackage{fancyhdr} % pagestyle
%---- Dimensions des marges ---
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm}
%\usepackage{setspace}
%\onehalfspacing
%----
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\newtheorem{definition}{Définition}
\newtheorem{proposition}{Proposition}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Théorème}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
\begin{definition}
aaaaa
\end{definition}

\begin{proposition}
bbbbb
\end{proposition}

\begin{theorem}
ccccc
\end{theorem}
\end{document}
```

I get

[image]

> I want to create 3 different blocks with `\bclogo` like the following pictures

[image]

[image]

Comment: Take a look at the documentation of `bclogo`. There are several examples of use.

Comment: I see it but I don't understand how to take each definition or propistion or theorme automatically

Comment: Maybe a solution in [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/444278/6880).

Comment: @projetmbc Thanks. It is a very nice post. But it does not solve my question.

Comment: What are the missing features?

Comment: @projetmbc I cannot reproduce the pictures in my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a starting code which is a small adaptation of the code in [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/444278/6880).

[image]

```
% Source: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/444278/6880

\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}

\usepackage[tikz]{bclogo}


\newcounter{deftheoandco}
\counterwithin{deftheoandco}{section}


\newenvironment{definition}{
    \refstepcounter{deftheoandco}
    \begin{bclogo}[couleur = blue!10,
                   logo = \bcplume]{Définition \thedeftheoandco}
}{
    \end{bclogo}
}


\newenvironment{example}{
    \refstepcounter{deftheoandco}
    \begin{bclogo}[couleur = white!10,
                   logo = \bccle]{Exemple \thedeftheoandco}
}{
    \end{bclogo}
}


\newenvironment{theorem}{
    \refstepcounter{deftheoandco}
    \begin{bclogo}[couleur = blue!10,
                   logo = \bcplume]{Théorème \thedeftheoandco}
}{
    \end{bclogo}
}


\newenvironment{proof}{
    \begin{bclogo}[couleur = white!10,
                   logo = \bccle]{Démonstration}
}{
    \end{bclogo}
}


\newcommand\blabla{Bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla...}

\begin{document} 

\section{C'est un début...}

\begin{definition}
    \blabla{}
\end{definition}

\begin{example}
    \blabla{}
\end{example}

\begin{proof}
    \blabla{}
\end{proof}

\begin{theorem}
    \blabla{}
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks Professor for the answer. If I want the numeroation of definitions theorems ..is not dependent on section That is Définition 1 and then Définition 2 ...what should I do?

Comment: Just comment the line `\counterwithin{deftheoandco}{section}`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This works perfectly